# Center Form Table

Tags: html, css

I have a table that looks like this

```
<form >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td> <td><input  type="text" name="name"></td><br>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Password :</td> <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I want to center the `<input>` in this table, so that the `<input>` fields are centered, not so that the whole table is center, when I do `<table align="center">` the whole thing is centered but the input boxes off center, how can I align this so that the input boxes middle is the middle of the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next:

```
<tr style="text-align: center">
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this..

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin: auto;"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this doesn't align the input in the middle

Answer (score 0):

you should define in your css:

```
.align-center{
    text-align:center
}
```

and add the class to your tds

you should look at it here for the full example :
https://jsfiddle.net/zu14wown/

Comment: This doesn't align the td in the center of the page, it doesn't do it in your jsfiddle either

Comment: you want the td to be in the center of the page, or the input in the center of the td?